# Chrome extension publishing review process for an extension built using a js module bundler

Tags: javascript, webpack, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, esbuild

I want to know if anyone has successfully published a chrome extension built in React or more specifically using a js module bundler like webpack.

I am asking this mostly because of the review process of chrome extension publishing, which states that code obfuscation is not allowed (https://developer.chrome.com/docs/webstore/review-process/ the "Notable factors that increase review time" section) and I need to know if the use of bundlers counts as code obfuscation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Bundlers use minification, not obfuscation, so it's allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through the publishing process, the extension took a couple of days to be reviewed and there were no issues with it being developed using a bundler (vite in this case).

Also thanks to wOxxOm for pointing out that bundlers use minification instead of obfuscation.